# rvm gemset is empty after installing rails to it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, archlinux

I am trying to get a multiple ruby/rails environment set up with rvm but I am having some problems.

If I try to install a legacy rails version (say, ruby 1.8.7 / rails 2.0.2) it goes through the motions but no gems are present at the end of the process. For example:

```
$ rvm install 1.8.7-head
$ rvm use ruby-1.8.7-head@rails-2.0.2 --create
$ gem install -v=2.0.2 rails
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

$
```

If I install ruby ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails it works fine.

I am on ArchLinux and I am using the rvm multi-user setup. I have created a non-root account to set up rvm, install the rubies and the gemsets.I have installed rubies ruby-1.8.7-head, ruby-1.8.7-p358 and ruby-1.9.3-p0.

The install of ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails worked fine but the install of ruby1.8.7 and rails-2.0.2 did not. It goes through the motions of an install but the gems aren't there when it finished.

I've added a transcript showing the exact commands I used here: http://pastebin.com/msa3u6w6.

I have followed closely the [ArchLinux tutorial](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/RVM) and the information on the RVM site also. Having spent several hours trying to fix this, I'd be grateful if anyone can help me.

My rvm info is below:

```
$ rvm info

ruby-1.8.7-head@rails-2.0.2:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux railsdev1 3.2.1-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Mon Jan 23 12:40:01 UTC 2012 x86_64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 CPU 920 @ 2.67GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.20(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.10.3 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]"
    updated:      "2 hours 12 minutes 19 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.9.3p125"
    date:         "2012-02-16"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-02-16 revision 34643"
    full_version: "ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-linux]"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails-2.0.2"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/usr/local/rvm/bin"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails-2.0.2"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@rails-2.0.2:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-head/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       "rails-2.0.2"


$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***


$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have errors running `rvm install 1.8.7-head` basically 1.8.7 is already old release and you should have no interest in running head version, try instead:

```
rvm get head
rvm use 1.8.7@rails-2.0.2 --install --create
```

This will install & use ruby 1.8.7-p358 (the current patchlevel as of writing this).

Comment: I will go away and try this but it also happened when I used p358 explicitly. I can quickly re-start my environment from scratch so I'll do that and give it a try...

Comment: Arch Linux puts "gem: --user=install" in /etc/gemrc. This needs to be commented out when using rvm.